# Zabbix configure AWS Cognito Authentication

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, zabbix

I have on AWS a Zabbix cluster HA with three EC2 instances with a Network Load Balancer.
Now I would like to configure access using AWS Cognito, but I don't found any guide for it.

Is there someone could help me on it please?
I have the cognito configuration, but I don't know which parameter I need to set in Zabbix.

In Zabbix what is an example for this values in Users -> Authentication -> SAML settings:
Code:

```
IdP entity ID
SSO service URL
Username attribute
SP entity ID
```

This are my Cognito settings:

```
User pool name auth.mydomain.com
User pool ID eu-west-1_XXXXXXX
Cognito domain https://myapp.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com
App client name saml-zabbix
Client ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX​
```

Thanks in adavnce for your support.